# private void formKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt)

Tags: java

> I have no idea how to use this please can someone explain and please don't give me negative votes

Comment: Check the [official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)

Comment: You're kind of asking for a votebomb by a) asking for a not-votebomb and more importantly b) not reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your question.   So, maybe you should not do those two things...?

Answer (score 0):

java's awt.KeyEvent does not have a method called formKeyPressed(). This must be in a KeyListener or KeyAdapter subclass code that you have written.